# How to get exact measurements of a div scroll and height, using em units makes it harder

Tags: javascript, html, onscroll

I have a chat for mobile website, and for the chat bubbles sizes we are using `em` units. Because of that, the elements seem to always be not-round numbers (like 510.673). I need to know the exact sizes, so I can know when to show a certain button, and when can I start loading older chat messages in that conversation.
Here is the html

```
<div class="chat-window">
    <div id="chatWindow" class="item-content" style="height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
</div>
```

The `overflow: auto;` is needed because without it, I don't receive a call when the top of the div is reached.

Here is the javascript, that is attached as an event to the `chatWindow` element

```
$('#chatWindow').on('scroll', onScroll);
```

and this is the onScroll function

```
   onScroll() {
        const chatWindow = $('#chatWindow');
        const scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollTop();
        const scrollHeight = chatWindow[0].scrollHeight;
        const clientHeight = chatWindow[0].clientHeight;
        if (scrollTop <= 0) {
            // When top is reached
            isInBottom = false;
            // more code
        } else if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight) {
            // When bottom is reached
            isInBottom = true;
            // more code
        } else {
            // When anywhere else
            isInBottom = false;
        }
    }
```

So this is what the chat bubbles look like, when they are with em units
[image]

They are not round numbers, so the scroll function can't calculate them accurately.

I tried with the `chatWindow[0].getBoundingClientRect().height` instead of `chatWindow[0].clientHeight`, it works, but only for that one parameter, I also need the other two to be with exact numbers with floating point.

How can I do it?

Comment: _“I need to know the exact sizes, so I can know when to show a certain button, and when can I start loading older chat messages in that conversation”_ – why would you need “exact” values for that? (Weird understanding of “exact”, btw. - 510.673 would be the _exact_ value here, you want something different.) You are not comparing the scroll position using equality, right? For that one usually uses greater that/lesser than comparisons.

Answer (score -1):

Could you please explain more?

chatWindow[0].getBoundingClientRect() will return an object which will have 'height' as of the keys.

```
chatWindow[0].getBoundingClientRect().height === chatWindow[0].clientHeight
```

Plus rest of the values in the objects are relative to ViewPort. This will impact your calculation  too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: yes, I meant chatWindow[0].getBoundingClientRect().height. That returns 510.8125 and chatWindow[0].clientHeight returns 510

Comment: I researched more. I doubt, fractional scroll offsets are currently supported. Read Here,

Main thread touch scrolling doesn't support fractional offsets
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414283

Comment: Also, here,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY,

it says,
"In practice, the returned value is a double-precision floating-point value indicating the number of pixels the document is currently scrolled vertically from the origin, where a positive value means the content is scrolled to upward. If the document is rendered on a subpixel-precise device, then the returned value is also subpixel-precise and may contain a decimal component. If the document isn't scrolled at all left or right, then scrollY is 0."